# I can't change my database password

Tags: mysql, wamp

I've been trying to change my root password on one of my  mySQL databases on WAMP server. However, when I submit my password MySQL says I have a fatal javascript error--token mismatch. Does anybody know how to fix this? I've already tried re-installing WAMP.
Thanks

Comment: Try cleaning your history and clear your cookies. See if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you  can acces database via shell. you can easily change your password

```
mysql -u root

UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
```

Comment: the command line suggestion did work however I did it slightly differently.Thanks